# Do I need to install Ubuntu desktop before installing Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, system-installation, inspiron

I have an old Windows Vista Dell Inspiron E1705 laptop. After my research I have found that it is capable of handling Ubuntu server. I want to REPLACE Windows vista with Ubuntu server 16.4.3. Do I need to install Ubuntu Desktop before installing Ubuntu server?
Does the iso server file created on DVD disk have capability of erasing the existing Windows Vista operating system & replacing it with the Ubuntu server 16.4.3?
I don't want to create a dual boot (Vista & Ubuntu) system. I want to replace the Vista with Ubuntu.
Clear helpful instructions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### The Ubuntu desktop and Ubuntu server are two different products

You can install **either** the desktop **or** the server. There is no need to install one and then the other, unless you want two separate Ubuntu installation in your laptop.

Note, the server is only command line. There is no point and click on the server. In the server you have to type all your commands. If you don't know what to type, then you can't use it. The user interface looks something like:

[image]

If this is what you want, then install the server.

If you are used to icons and pretty buttons, then you may want the desktop. The desktop looks like:

[image]

If you want a graphical user interface (GUI) but don't want the standard Ubuntu, then you can try [XUbuntu](https://xubuntu.org/) or [LUbuntu](https://lubuntu.net/). Also see other [options for low memory systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems).

Hope this helps

Comment: LOL! That's a very impressive comparison! You _can_ however convert a server installation into a desktop installation but nobody would do that voluntarily: you would need to install a graphical environment, all the GUI programs (like FireFox, LibreOffice, Video and Sound software, Gedit, ...) and finally re-configure Ubuntu because the server edition is optimized to run as a server (different services with different settings) whereas the desktop edition is optimized for desktop usage.